# What's the difference of these geo-based notification approaches on iOS?

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager, uilocalnotification

I'm looking for a way to implement geo-based notifications on iOS.
I found two ways but I couldn't figure out which one is the best and the difference.

1: Using CLLocationManager's startMonitoring
Like this tutorial.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial

2: Using CLLocationManager's startMonitoring and UILocalNotification's region.

Like this code:

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello!"];
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    CLCircularRegion *region = nil;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(geoPoint.latitude,
                                                                 geoPoint.longitude);
    if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(location)){
        region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:location
                                                   radius:50.0
                                               identifier:@"region1"];

        region.notifyOnExit = NO;

        localNotif.region = region;
        localNotif.regionTriggersOnce = YES;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

    } else {
        NSDictionary *info = @{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"Invalid coordinate info."};
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"InvalidCLLocationError"
                                             code:1999
                                         userInfo:info];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show notifications when the app is dismissed you should use the `UILocalNotification` approach. This is because CLLocationManager's `startMonitoring` will stop working after your app is dismissed. You're basically setting up a Geofence when using `UILocalNotification`.

You'll have to implement CLLocationManager's `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` delegate methods. In those methods you'll set the local notifications.

Please note: As of iOS 10, `UILocalNotification` is deprecated. Please use `UNNotificationRequest` instead.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification